# How to put Syncfusion win phone chart custom palette with conditions

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, charts, syncfusion, color-palette

I have a win phone chart control and want to show data based on three condition. So I am using a bar series and each bar satisfy any one of the three condition. So I just want to show bars in three different colors each for a condition.

```
<chart:ColumnSeries Label="Series1" ItemsSource="{Binding CategoricalDatas}"

                XBindingPath="Category" YBindingPath="Value" Palette="Custom">   <chart:ColumnSeries.ColorModel>

   <chart:ChartColorModel>

       <chart:ChartColorModel.CustomBrushes>

           <SolidColorBrush Color="#F02B2C"/>

           <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF3B5C"/>

           <SolidColorBrush Color="#F06B3C"/>

           <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFB6C"/>

           <SolidColorBrush Color="#F0FB8C"/>

        </chart:ChartColorModel.CustomBrushes>

    </chart:ChartColorModel>

</chart:ColumnSeries.ColorModel>
```

This is a simple way to put different colors for bars. How I specify condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the condition in Chart Series ColorModel converter and you can return custom brush based on specified condition as like the below code snippet.

Code Snippet[C#]:

```
    viewmodel model1 = new viewmodel();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        model1.CustomBrush = new List<Brush>();
        foreach (var item in model1.Products)
        {
            if (item.mark >= 80)
            {
                model1.CustomBrush.Add(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green));

            }
            else if (item.mark < 50)
            {
                model1.CustomBrush.Add(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
            }
            else if (item.mark > 50 && item.mark < 80)
            {
                model1.CustomBrush.Add(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue));
            }
        }
        ChartColorModel model = new ChartColorModel();
        model.CustomBrushes = model1.CustomBrush;
        return model;

    }
```

Regards,

Sheik

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same answer from Sync support also. Thanks to Sync quick support